# Where to start on client side for Webots Web Simulation to create my own instance of RobotBenchmark

Tags: client, simulation, webots

I am working to create my own instance of Webots RobotBenchmark to teach high school students Robotics and Python for online learning.

I have established a cohosted, VMware based Ubuntu based session server and simulation server.  Webot runs on the server.  The web streaming interface is working (very slowly).

Trying to establish the web simulation. I've read the Web Simulation documentation over and over again but not making any progress.   With the chrome browser, I can successfully run the HTTP .... /monitor command on both servers.  I am confused on how to implement the webots.min.js on the client as described in the simulation protocol sequence diagram.  I've poked around the code base and see the wwi folder under the "resources/web/wwi" folder.  Not sure how to use these resources...

I could use a pointer to documentation on where to start on how to implement the "User/Client" "Start Simulation" part of the protocol.

Thank you,
Dave Frederick

Mr. David Frederick
OHS – Career and Technology Education – Robotics, Cybersecurity, Programming, and Digital Electronics
B.S. Electrical Engineering, CISSP, CompTIA A+ and Network+
Osbourn High School, Manassas, VA
My Web site:   https://www.mcpsva.org/Domain/1302

Comment: The full source code of robotbenchmark is available [here](https://robotbenchmark.net/robotbenchmark.zip). Basically, `webots.min.js` should be copied from the `webots/resources/web/wwi` folder to your web site, so that it is available online and can be included in your web pages showing the simulation.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.
I have established a LAMP server and deployed Webots and the robotbenchmar code.  I have a number of the PHP files working.

I am getting failures when the PHP files need to access the database. My MySQL server is empty.  ( I have figured out where to enter the SQL root name and PW

I am currently stuck on creating the 'robotbenchmark' database within MySQL.
 
Is there any guidance on the required tables and data for this DB?

Thank you,

Comment: A new version of the full source code was uploaded [here](https://robotbenchmark.net/robotbenchmark.zip) which now includes the database structure in `robotbenchmark/database/structure.sql`. I hope this help.